# ANDROID: Adapter position returns to zero and re-adds views to ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

My app requires the ability to add several views on one line in a user selected order.

I found this tutorial which seems to accomplish what I want with a bit of modification.

```
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/
```

Having followed the tutorial and made the required changes, the code works except for one strange issue. The position increments but when it hits ~9 it returns to zero and then re-adds views that are already in the list and thus never reaches the >9 ones.

Also, if I scroll down to the bottom and then back up the very first entry has changed! It may change more but I haven't checked that.

Through some tests I have discovered that the textSize has some effect. If I set it small enough so that all 'rows' will show on screen at once then they appear fine.

This is my listview layout that gets inflated into the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="60dip"
  style="@style/DefaultTheme">
    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/Line01"
      android:layout_width="5dip"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#F00" />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/Line02"
      android:layout_width="5dip"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#0F0" />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/Line03"
      android:layout_width="5dip"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#00F"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="2dip">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/Name"
          android:text="Name"
          style="@style/Name" />
        <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/Status"
          android:text="Status"
          style="@style/Status" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/StatusImage"
      style="@style/StatusImage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I change background colours and text but that is all. Any ideas what is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb for asking this now and not going back over the tutorial completely.

I was setting the values in my layout I place in the ListView on my main layout only when a new ViewHolder was created. Thus when I scrolled, the views were recycled, but never updated with the correct View settings.

All working fine now!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

That's because ListView recycles Views. It creates as many Views as required then the one which isn't available will be recycled as next.

So you have to set the colors/attributes in the getView or bindView methods of the adapter.

And btw. what you posted doesn't inflate the ListView, as there is no `' object in it. At best it could be a single ListView item, but not the listview itself ^^

Comment: I may not fully understand what inflate means then... this layout is added to the ListView in my main layout :S

Comment: All details for text and colours are set in the getView method of the adapter and all appear correctly when they appear. My problem is that the position gets reset and the same layout is added to the list view a second time